# EditText com Máscara

Tags: java, android

Eu precisava de uma máscara para um horimetro de trator com 5 campos uma virgula e mais um capo depois.
Exemplo: `"#####,#"`
Eu até achei um MaskEdit legal, segue o link:
https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText
O Único problema é que eu preciso que o 'hint' do EditText esteja com o texto `"Horimetro *"` e acaba que a máscara come os caracteres do hint fazendo com que fique `"Horim,e"`
Gostaria de saber se existe uma solução para isso ou se existe algum outro MaskEdit que sirva para mim

Answer (score 0):

Procure usar um TextWatcher e coloque o hint em seu XML. Abaixo um exemplo de máscara de CEP:

```
EditText edtTextCEP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_txt_cep);    
TextWatcher textWatcherCep = Mask.insert("#####-###", edtTextCEP);
edtTextCEP.addTextChangedListener(textWatcherCep);
```